# I am currently trying to save a set of integers in a int array, by redefining string into numbers, then store it in the array

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, integer

I am trying to convert input text/numbers (string), which will include any characters, but I want to separate the numbers from the characters and store them into an integer array, once it is converted from a string.

I believe the problem is where the string is converting to an integer by use of `stoi()`, but I cannot seem to spot the problem.

Currently, the code accepts any input and turns it into a string, the string is then checked character by character, and all the numbers without separation with comma or space is added together, once a comma or space, or any other character separates the number, the number as a whole is added to the array, and then continues to check the string for more numbers.

Any ideas?
Input Example1: 12, 13, 15
    Input Example2: 12 13 15
        Input Example3: 12ab13cd15ef

Result in integer array: 0[12] 1[13] 2[15]
These numbers will be used in the specific order, by using the numbers within the array.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string datainput, str1, str3;
    cin >> datainput;
    int n = 0, raycount = 0, c;
    int myray[10];
    while (datainput[n])
    {
        if (datainput[n] == ('0') || datainput[n] == ('1') || datainput[n] == ('2') || datainput[n] == ('3') || datainput[n] == ('4') ||
            datainput[n] == ('5') || datainput[n] == ('6') || datainput[n] == ('7') || datainput[n] == ('8') || datainput[n] == ('9'))
        {
            str1 = datainput[n];
            str3 += str1;
        }
        else
        {
            c= stoi(str3);
            c >> myray[raycount];
            raycount++;
        }
        n++;
    }
    cout << myray[0] << endl;
    cout << myray[1] << endl;
    cout << myray[2] << endl;
    cout << myray[3] << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see quite a few issues with your code.

- Prior to C++11, `while (datainput[n])` has *undefined behavior* once `n` reaches the end of the string.
- The way you are checking for numeric digits can be greatly simplified using `std::isdigit()`, or even just a simple range check using the `>=` and `<=` operators.
- You are not correctly accounting for numbers that are separated by other characters, or when the last number in the string is at the very end of the string.
- The statement `c >> myray[raycount];` needs to be changed to `myray[raycount] = c;` instead.  And you are not breaking your loop if `raycount` reaches the max capacity of `myray[]`.
- You are not resetting `str3` back to an blank string after converting it with `std::stoi()`.  You just keep appending new digits to the end of previous digits with no break in between numbers.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string datainput, str3;
    cin >> datainput;

    int myray[10];
    int raycount = 0;

    bool gettingDigits = false;

    for (int n = 0; n < datainput.size(); ++n)
    {
        char ch = datainput[n];

        //if (isdigit(ch))
        if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        {
            if (!gettingDigits)
            {
                str3 = "";
                gettingDigits = true;
            }

            str3 += ch;
        }
        else
        {
            if (gettingDigits)
            {
                myray[raycount] = stoi(str3);
                raycount++;
                str3 = "";
                gettingDigits = false;
                if (raycount == 10) break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (gettingDigits && (raycount < 10))
    {
        myray[raycount] = stoi(str3);
        raycount++;
    }

    for (int n = 0; n < raycount; ++n)
        cout << myray[n] << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/x5YKAZ)

Alternatively:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string datainput, str3;
    cin >> datainput;

    int myray[10];
    int raycount = 0;

    string::size_type start = datainput.find_first_of("0123456789");
    string::size_type end;

    while (start != string::npos)
    {
        end = datainput.find_first_not_of("0123456789", start+1);
        if (end == string::npos)
        {
            str3 = datainput.substr(start);
            myray[raycount] = stoi(str3);
            raycount++;
            break;
        }

        str3 = datainput.substr(start, end-start);
        myray[raycount] = stoi(str3);
        raycount++;
        if (raycount == 10) break;

        start = datainput.find_first_of("0123456789", end+1);
    }

    for (int n = 0; n < raycount; ++n)
        cout << myray[n] << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/mNrLkx)

Comment: Thank you for your input! I have applied some of the changes you suggested, and it is steps in the right direction. Also highly appreciate the other methods which will make the code easier. Resetting the strings and integer seemed to fix the stacking problem, but I am still stuck on getting all the numbers stacked into the array, and the conversion of the string to a number. I will browse through the code you posted and see if I further can solve my problem. :-)

Comment: @Daniel it would be helpful if you would edit your question to show the actual input you are typing in, and what the expected result should look like.

Comment: I have added 3 examples, which should produce the same result.

Comment: @Daniel I updated my answer. There was an error in my first example, which I have fixed.

Answer (score -1):

So, you want to segregate numbers and characters into different arrays.
In if block, you are checking for characters, so, I suspect stoi() wouldn't work.
Better typecast it to an integer.

```
int temp[10];

if (datainput[n] == ('0') || ...) {
            temp[n] = int(datainput[n]);
        }
```

This way your temp array would contain the numbers.

Comment: I would be grateful if you tell me why is this answer downvoted ? Thanks.